# DateFormatter Swift 3

Tags: swift, datetime, datepicker, formatting

So I am creating a contact phonebook app and I am trying to get the keyboard to display as a `DateTimePicker`.

I have gotten the keyboard to work after some time but I can't seem to get the formatter working correctly.

```
@IBOutlet weak var datetxt: UITextField!

var datepicker = UIDatePicker()


func createdatepicker() {
    datepicker.datePickerMode = .date

    let toolbar = UIToolbar()
    toolbar.sizeToFit()

    let donebutton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .done, target: self, action: #selector(doneac))
    toolbar.setItems([donebutton], animated: true)
    datetxt.inputAccessoryView = toolbar

    datetxt.inputView = datepicker

}

func doneac() {
    let Date = DateFormatter()
    Date.dateStyle = .short
    //Date.string(from: String)
    datetxt.text = "\(datepicker.date)"
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}
```

When I run the app it selects the date but, it also shows the time in the text field.

Comment: Set the `timeStyle` as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not using your `DateFormatter`. The `datetxt.text = "\(datepicker.date)"` simply sets the `text` to the `description` of the date picker's date (which includes date and time). But you're not using your formatter at all.

And, by the way, I wouldn't use `Date` for the name of the date formatter. One would generally use `formatter` or `dateFormatter`. `Date` only invites confusion with the Swift type of the same name.

Thus, you might do:

```
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateStyle = .short
datetxt.text = formatter.string(from: datepicker.date)
```

Answer (score -1):

here you can make use of formatter you had not showed any date formatter you used

```
        //here is current date
        let date = Date()

        //formatter to return value as 21-11-2017
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy"

        //Date Output
        let result = formatter.string(from: date)

        //second formatter to return time format like 2:31 Am
        let formatter1 = DateFormatter()
        formatter1.dateFormat = "h:mm a"

        //Time Output
        let result1 = formatter1.string(from: date)

        //set values for example using label for reference 
        DateLabel.text = result
        TimeLabel.text = result1

        //actual output is as Follows:
        DateLabel = 21-11-2107
        TimeLabel = 9:54 AM
```